# Start fragment in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working with a simple app with Bottom Navigation View.
I have 3 fragment with text, and i want to start their when i select a item in Botton Navigation, but i don't know what to write in the MainActivity.java;
All the fragments have a .xml layout and .java.
I searched in some codes, i wrote them, i search videos, but i have no sucess.

I'm learning about Fragments and UI Dynamic, so i created a new project in Android Studio with Bottom Navigation Activity.
So, in my activity_main i have 3 itens in Bottom Navigation, and one framelayout above Bottom Navigation, taking all the parent. The idea is: when i select a item in Bottom Navigation, it will show another layout in the framelayout. So i created 3 xml layouts (with java class too) in layout folder and one fragment in framelayout. Now, i'm trying to show these layouts in my framelayout(that have a fragment) when i select a item. But i don't know how to do that.

Main Activity`

```
private TextView mTextMessage;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                selectedFragment = DashboardFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                selectedFragment = NotificationsFragment.newInstance();
                break;
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, HomeFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

activity_main xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="bandeira.thalisson.barradenavegacaoembaixo.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
```

navigation xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/Fragment_one"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_home"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/Fragment_two"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_dashboard"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/Fragment_three"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_notifications"/>
```

Fragment.java example

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_home, container, false);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_home, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, in your activity_main.xml we don't require 3 different fragments as we can replace or add our any selected Fragment in 1 FrameLayout only.
Secondly, when ever the user select any one from the Bottom NavigationView just get an instance of the related Fragment class and replace it with your activity_main's FrameLayout .

```
Fragment selectedFragment = null;
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.navigation_home:
                   selectedFragment = FunFragment.newInstance();
                   break;
```

after getting the instance of the selected Fragment replace it with you activity_main's FrameLayout as to show on the screen.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment);
            transaction.commit();
```

**EDIT TAG**
**Step 1.** your activity_main.xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.exampl.MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2.** Your fragment_home.xml layout should be like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="android"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Make 3 different fragment layout for your three different options

**Step 3.** your MainActivity.java class will be like this

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        selectedFragment = FunFragment.newInstance();
                       break;
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        selectedFragment = TheoryFragment.newInstance();
                       break;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                        selectedFragment = AndroidFragment.newInstance();
                        break;
                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        };

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, FunFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

In on create replace with the fragment which you want to show after launching the application and navigation listener will take care of what ever option you will select

**Step 4.** Your will have 3 different Fragment class and look like this

```
public class TheoryFragment extends Fragment {

     public static TheoryFragment newInstance() {
            TheoryFragment fragment = new TheoryFragment();
            return fragment;
        }
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_theory, container, false);
            unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you, let me know if any problem.

Comment: My app forces close

Comment: @TonyStarkus could you plz share the code, what changes you made !!

Comment: Yes. I fogot to say that my app is starting with a fragment. Because i have 3 menus in Bottom Navigation, and the app is starting in firts menu iten, that is a fragment. In this case, i think that my firts screen app can't be a fragment right ? The first screen must be the main layout

Comment: And about the code, i just wrote what you suggested, and my MainActivity say that "cannot resolve selectedFragment" , "cannot resolve FragmentManager" and "cannot resolve fragment" . Think i forggot to declare anything. Ooh guys, i'm lost :(

Comment: @TonyStarkus
Ok, No problem... explaining step by step in the above answer **EDIT TAG**

Comment: Man, more one problem. My app start with Home item. But when i click in other itens, the framelayout don't update. No force close, i just select a item and nothen happen.

Comment: Did you implement your other two fragment classes and their layouts properly ?

Comment: Yes. I removed this line: "unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);" because Android Studio cannot resolve "unbinder" and "ButterKnife".

And, in my activity_main.xml i removed "fragment" in the Framelayout.

Comment: ok, as i have given the activity_main.xml use as it is, put different texts in 3 different fragments you have created and attached with your 3 different fragment classes. Let me know if problem occur.

Comment: I did it. This is how i discovered that the framelayout is not updating.

My app is starting with homefragment (that is the firts fragment). So, i switch to the second fragment, but my app is starting with firts fragment !!! Same happen if i try to start in third fragment, my app will always start in firts, and don't will update.

Comment: Could you please update your code in the question, So that I can have a look to it?

Comment: make `return rootView;` in your HomeFragment.java class and check the same with your other fragment class too...

Comment: Look this, in my fragment class, i i'm saying to inflate the fragment in the container, container is my LinearLayout.
I think the correct is to inflate in my Framelayout (id/content)

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_home, container, false);

Answer (score 3):

Take three Fragments like HomeFragment,DashboardFragment and NotificationFragment and three layouts for those three fragments.

**HomeFragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home Fragment"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**DashboardFragment **

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    public DashboardFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_dashboard.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dashboard Fragment"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**NotificationFragment **

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {
    public NotificationFragment () {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_notification.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notification Fragment"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is Your activity.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.Fragment_one:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.Fragment_two:
                        fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.Fragment_three:
                        fragment = new NotificationFragment();
                        break;
                }
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: My MainActivity is saying that "cannot resolve symbol "fragment" " in "fragment = new HomeFragment();" and the other three too.

Comment: U can accept my answrer if it helped you. U most welcome.

Comment: Man, more one problem. My app start with Home item. But when i click in other itens, the framelayout don't update. No force close, i just select a item and nothen happen.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add, if you wanted to use your `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()`to select your start fragment you can use the `setSelectedItemId()` e.g. :

Replace '**R.id.navigation_home**' with your own start fragment.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

alone with create this methor

```
protected boolean openFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, fragment)
            .commit();
    return true;
}
```

to edit in the switch

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home: return openFragment(OneFragment.newInstance("",""));
            case R.id.navigation_beehive: return openFragment(twoFragment.newInstance("",""));
            case R.id.navigation_notifications: return openFragment(otherFragment.newInstance("",""));
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and for to finalize you can to initialize with a fragment in

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    openFragment(OneFragment.newInstance("",""));
}
```