# Bottom Navigation View not updating RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Hi I am using Bottom Navigation in my app, I have three tabs at bottom, and I have three different fragments. Whenever user changes tab from bottom, it should show relative RecyclerView data, but the issue is in all three tabs it shows one RecyclerView. it shows RecyclerView of ItemOneFragment in all three tabs.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                      //  Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.navigation_home:
                                Fragment selectedFragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                                transaction.commit();
                                break;
                            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                                Fragment Englishsfrag = ItemTwoFragment.newInstance();
                                FragmentTransaction transactiontwo = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transactiontwo.replace(R.id.frame_layout, Englishsfrag);
                                transactiontwo.commit();
                                break;
                            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                                Fragment mixfrag = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance();
                                FragmentTransaction transactionthree = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transactionthree.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mixfrag);
                                transactionthree.commit();
                                break;
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                });

        //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, ItemOneFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();

        //Used to select an item programmatically
        //bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code where `Recyclerview` implemented

Comment: its really big code and not able to complete file,it is three different fragment,, i am using default navigation structure provided by studio..

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338835/start-fragment-in-bottomnavigationview/44340557#44340557

Comment: here is your code is correct but I have to see your recyclerview code any link of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove creating **`FragmentTransaction`**  for every case.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
      (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
      Fragment selectedFragment = null;
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_item1:
      selectedFragment = ItemOnFragment.newInstance();
      break;
      case R.id.action_item2:
      selectedFragment = ItemTwoFragment.newInstance();
      break;
      case R.id.action_item3:
      selectedFragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance();
      break;
      case R.id.action_item4:
      selectedFragment = ItemFourFragment.newInstance();
      break;
      }
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().
    beginTransaction();
      transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
      transaction.commit();
      return true;
      }
      });

      //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().
    beginTransaction();
      transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, ItemOnFragment.newInstance());
      transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to do in following way

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    fragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance();

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    //  Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_home:
                            fragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                            fragment = ItemTwoFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                            fragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                    }
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```